# Converting a Outlook mail attachment to byte array with C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook

*Fair warning*: I'm a little bit of a rookie to `C#` and to Outlook, so bear with me on this.

I've been experimenting with emails in Outlook for a quick and dirty addin I'm building, but the addin requires me to send attached files to a different system.

Long story short; in order to do this I need to convert an Outlook item's mail attachment into a `byte` array.

What I have thus far (and the complete code is obviously miles longer than this, but I'm sure we all have better things to do than to sit and read page up and page down of code):

```
Outlook.Selection sel = control.Context as Outlook.Selection;
Outlook.MailItem mail = sel[1];
Outlook.Attachment a = mail.Attachments[0];
```

Problem is, that I have no idea how to convert `a` to a `byte` array.

**PS:** I know there are about a billion answers as to how to convert a `byte` array to a mail, but none to explain how to get it running the other way around.

**EDIT 1:** I would rather not have to save the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second method proposed by Dmitry (open attachment as binary stream) is also achievable in managed code. It uses the PropertyAccessor interface, which is available for Attachment objects in C#. Here is some sample code I've used successfully in my own project:

```
const string PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

Outlook.Attachment attachment = mail.Attachments[0];  

// Retrieve the attachment as a byte array
var attachmentData =
    attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN);
```

My example code is based on the **How to: Modify an Attachment of an Outlook Email Message** topic provided by *Ken Getz, MCW Technologies, LLC* as part of the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/hh290849.aspx).

Comment: Keep in mind that older versions of Outlook can have a problem retrieving large binary properties such as PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, especially in the online Exchange mode.

Comment: hmm getting an error on that last line. I verified that there is at least 1 attachment:  Array index out of bounds.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko what are the older versions of Outlook ? Is that ok for outlook 2010 ?

Comment: "older" as in Outlook 2013 or older. It can still happen even in Outlook 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Save the attachment ([Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219926(v=office.12).aspx)) to a file, then open the file as a byte stream.
2. If you were using C++ or Delphi, you could use [IAttach::OpenProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446007.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)`(PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN, IID_IStream, ..)` to open the attachment as IStream COM object.
3. If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes the `AsArray` property on the [Attachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/safe_Attachment.htm) and [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not really what I was looking for. I'd prefer not having to save it to a file, I'm not using C++ or Delphi, and Redemption is sadly not an option.

Comment: Alright, if no one can come up with a better solution in a while, I'll give you best answer.

Comment: You need to save the attachment to the disk and then read it as byte stream. Or you need to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI. Outlook and Redemption are just wrappers around that API which allows to read attachments as a byte stream.

Comment: `Attachment.SaveAsFile` this method is working fine for attachments. But I also want to save embedded image like signature. An exception `Cannot save the attachment. Cannot add the attachment; no data source was provided.` occurs when we save embedded images @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Is that a regular olByValue attachment? Or an OLE (ollOle) attachment?